# why does apache/server die when i make a typo and cause a never ending loop?

Tags: php, apache, apache2, freeze

this is more of a fundamental question at how apache/threading works.
in this hypothetical (read: sometimes i suck and write terrible code), i write some code that enters the infinite-recursion phases of it's life. then, what's expected, happens. the serve stalls.

even if i close the tab, open up a new one, and hit the site again (locally, of course), it does nothing. even if i hit a different domain i'm hosting through a vhost declaration, nothing. i normally have to wait a number of seconds before apache can begin handling traffic again. most of the time i just get tired and restart the server manually.

can someone explain this process to me? i have the php runtime setting 'ignore_user_abort' set to true to allow ajax calls that are initiated to keep running even if they close their browser, but would this being set to false affect it?

any help would be appreciated. didn't know what to search for.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ignore_user_abort()` allows your script (and Apache) to ignore a user disconnecting (closing browser/tab, moving away from page, hitting ESC, esc..) and continue processing. This is useful in some cases - for instance in a shopping cart once the user hits "yes, place the order". You really don't want an order to die halfway through the process, e.g. order's in the database, but the charge hasn't been sent to the payment facility yet. Or vice-versa.

However, while this script is busilly running away in "the background", it will lock up resources on the server, especially the session file - PHP locks the session file to make sure that multiple parallel requests won't stomp all over the file, so while your infinite loop is running in the background, you won't be able to use any session-enabled other part of the site. And if the loop is intensive enough, it could tie up the CPU enough that Apache is unable to handle any other requests on other hosted sites, where the session lock might not apply.

If it is an infinite loop, you'll have to wait until PHP's own maximum allowed run time ([`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/set_time_limit) and [`max_execution_time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)) kicks in and kills the script. There's also some server-side limiters, like Apache's [`RLimitCPU`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#rlimitcpu) and [`TimeOut`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout) that can handle situations like this.

Note that except on Windows, PHP doesn't count "external" time in the set_time_limit. So if your runaway process is doing database stuff, calling external programs via `system()` and the like, the time spent running those external calls is NOT accounted for in the parent's time limit.

Comment: Thanks Marc. That helps a tonne. I'll look into the Apache limiters and consider using ignore_user_abort only in certain areas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you write code that causes an (effectively) neverending loop, then apache will execute that, and be unable to respond to any additional new requests for a page, because it's trying to determine the page content (for the served page which caused the neverending loop) by executing the (non-terminating) php code.

Solution: don't write code that doesn't terminate (in a reasonable amount of time).  Understand loop invariants.

Comment: is there a way to prevent this? eg. an apache setting that ends any requests that have gone on for longer than x seconds? my php settings are setup to have a max execution time of 5 seconds, so why does it run non-stop?

Comment: @onassar: seriously, this is like the old Groucho Marx joke: "A man goes to the doctor, and says 'Doctor, it hurts when I do this; what can you do for me?' and the doctor says 'Don't do that.'".  Don't write code that enters an infinite / excessively deep loop.  Really.  Don't depend on apache or php settings to save you; just don't write code like that.  Really.

Comment: Thanks McWafflestix. I'm looking for a situation that helps catch the bugs that I write. If you have any suggestions I'm open to them, but if you're suggestion is 'dont write bad code', then I'll wait for a more helpful response. Thanks.

Comment: @onassar: I can understand that, but if you really want to catch the bugs you write, you've got to actually do something other than set a flag on apache or php and hope to find your bug.  Have you got logging for your recursive calls, so you can see where it's going out of control?  Have you tried profiling your code?  Would you care to post a simplified code sample to see if someone can actually help you find what might be the problem?  People here (including me) really want to help, but we also really want to see that you're trying something to solve your own problems.

Comment: I'm using an open-source script that provides a wordwrap function akin to php's native, but that is multibyte safe and html safe. The result is that 95% of the time it works, and 5% of the time it doesn't (which ends in the loop). My concern isn't trying to find the bug in the code (I can figure that out). Rather it lies in what I can't figure out. "you dont know what you dont know". I want to find a last-call effort to prevent some buggy code from breaking my server/user-experience. Does that make sense?

Comment: use something else that's better-written.

Comment: @sreservoir see comment above.

Comment: that is precisely the point. either fix it yourself, use something better-written, or wait for next version.